# MVC pass int from view to controller with a button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

Here is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        @:<div class="row">
    }
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:20px;">
        @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ClientDetail", "Client", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block", id = @item.id})

    </div>
    i++;
    if(i%4 == 0)
    {
        @:</div>
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

and here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult ClientDetail(int id)
{        
    ClientModel model = cserv.Get(id, User.Identity.GetUserId());
    ClientViewModel viewModel = new ClientViewModel(model);
    return View(viewModel);    
}
```

Every time I click on one of my links it gives me this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ClientDetail(Int32)' in 'TechUCRM.Controllers.ClientController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Why is my id parameter not being passed into the controller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to place id at **routeValues** argument.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ClientDetail", "Client", 
   new { id = item.id}, 
   new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block"})
```

Same as

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ClientDetail", "Client", 
    routeValues: new { id = item.id }, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block" })
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ClientDetail", "Client", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block", id = @item.id})
```

to:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ClientDetail", "Client", new{ id= item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block"})
```

one you used up there sets id attribute of HTML. it is not the Id for Routing.